# Python: Ошибка с eel: ReferenceError: eel is not defined

Tags: javascript, python, eel

Пишу программу с web-интерфейсом на питоне с модулем eel. Написал простой код, чтобы проверить работу eel, но мне выдает ошибку `Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: eel is not defined`

Вот код python

```
import eel

eel.init("app")

eel.start("index.html", size=(800, 1000))

@eel.expose
def test_py(value):
    return value + 1;
```

Вот js/html

```js
async function test() {
    let value = Math.floor(Math.random() * (10 - 1) + 1);
    let newValue = await eel.test_py(value);
    console.log(newValue);
}
document.querySelector(".stuff__option-test").addEventListener("click", test);
```

```html
<ul class="stuff__list">
    <li class="stuff__option stuff__option-test"><a href="#" class="stuff__option-link" target="_blank">test</a></li>
</ul>
<script src="./main.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Кто-нибудь подскажет что не так и как исправить ошибку?

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=Uncaught+(in+promise)+ReferenceError%3A+eel+is+not+defined

Comment: @nörbörnën хах, а ловко Вы это придумали! Но, после того как у меня появилась эта ошибка я сразу полез в гугл, полазив почти по всем сайтам, от стаковерфлоу до хабра, переписав код несколько раз, посмотрев гайды на ютубе, почитав документацию так ничего и не нашёл)

Comment: в строчке ``let newValue = await eel.test_py(value);`` что такое eel?